# How to compile scala files from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I could not find any relevant answer to my following question :

I'm trying to compile an existing scala and java project from eclipse.
I have installed the software from eclipse as well - but i'm still having errors.

[i.e - erros in scala class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxuo0.png)

What should i do in order to correctly compile the scala files?

Comment: Are you using the [Scala IDE plug-in](http://scala-ide.org/)?

Comment: Search this on Google -> `eclipse scala tutorial 2016`

Comment: Yes. I did those steps in the tutorial as well.

Comment: try adding scala nature: right-click on project -> configure > add scala nature

Comment: @slouc Thank you! everything works now!